# How to view files created within a Zeit Docker/Node container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, filesystems, vercel

According to [the Zeit docs](https://zeit.co/docs/deployment-types/docker#file-system-specifications)

> There are no limitations inside Docker deployments when it comes to the file system. It's always writable and readable.

And indeed my little test seems to write files successfully:

```
app.get('/write', (req, res) => {
  console.log({
    __dirname,
    cwd: process.cwd()
  })
  const text = `some bit of text`
  const dirpath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'uploads')
  const fullpath = path.resolve(dirpath, `file-${+new Date()}.txt`)
  mkdirp(dirpath, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error)
    } else {
      fs.writeFile(fullpath, text, error => {
        if (error) {
          console.error('error writing', error)
        } else {
          console.log(`file written at ${fullpath}`)
          fs.readdir(dirpath, function(err, items) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
              console.log(items[i])
            }
          })
          res.send('File written')
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

After several refreshes of the `/write` route, this will print the list of files. However within the Zeit "source" panel, I only see the files copied by my Dockerfile:

[image: output of source]

For reference, my [Dockerfile](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/):

```
FROM node:carbon

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ "start": "node ./build/server"
```

#### Within the Zeit/Now environment, is there any way to view/intereact with these files, via ssh or some other method?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. And that is because you can't access the state of the deployment, but only its source and logging!

It makes sense, after all, you should be running a stateless application...